# Including dependency packages in npm package

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babeljs, publishing

I am trying to publish an npm package and would like to bundle all the dependencies in it.... To explain a bit better below is my package.json and webpack config..

packageMain -> This is the repo for the published package

```
// package.json

{
    "name": "packageMain",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Blah blah",
    "main": "index.js",
    "author": "Batman"
    "scripts": {
        "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --bai
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "packageA": "1.0.0",
        "packageB": "1.0.1",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
        "babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "eslint": "^5.15.1",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
        "execa": "1.0.0",
        "webpack": "^4.29.6",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
    }
}
```

```
// webpack.config.js


const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');


module.exports = webpackMerge(baseComponentConfig, {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true
    }
});
```

Running `build` will generate a `index.js` with babelified es5 code.

**Problem:** The code of `packageA` and `packageB` does nott get  transpiled into `index.js`

Comment: It doesn't work that way. What in your code would make you think package A and package B would get merged together into a single file?

Comment: I mean am using those packages inside `src/blah.js` and other files... What I am looking for...

If theres a way to bundle everything with dependencies into 1 file that gets published to npm?
Or that isnt the correct way to of thinking

Comment: Okay but that still doesn't make sense. Why would the code of packageA and packageB get merged together? `./src/index.js` gets transpiled into `index.js`.

Comment: Problem am facing is... once I publish to npm... and then import it in another poject

I keep getting Module not found packageA

Comment: *Is* that a problem? When your package gets installed, it's dependencies will be added too.

Comment: Thats a completely different problem that what your question is suggesting. However, I know NPM packages can't have upper case letters in the name, so that probably has something to do with it.

Comment: What is `baseComponentConfig` in your `webpack.config.js`? Its value may have a significant effect.